# Capture content of xml feed that doesn't load immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have been pulling in an XML feed using Nokogiri and it has been working fine. A new feed has been added that I need to pull in and it doesn't load all at once. If I visit the xml feed in a browser, I can see an initial set of data load and then more data loads shortly thereafter. When I use Nokogiri, it just gets the initial set of data. I also tried to use curl to capture the feed and it gets the same result.

How can I get all of the data from the XML feed? Is there an option I can pass to Nokogiri or a flag I can set on curl? I looked at the Nokogiri documentation and the curl man page, but can't figure it out.

When I pull the data down (with Nokogiri or curl), it looks something like this (there are a lot more than 2 items though):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item-syndication version="5">
  <item id="1">
    <more-data >lorem ipsum</more-data>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <more-data >lorem ipsum</more-data>
  </item>
</item-syndication>
```

If I visit the url in a browser, it initially looks like the above, but then loads more items, like below (it ends up with a lot more than 4 items):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item-syndication version="5">
  <item id="1">
    <more-data >lorem ipsum</more-data>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <more-data >lorem ipsum</more-data>
  </item>
  <item id="3">
    <more-data >lorem ipsum</more-data>
  </item>
  <item id="4">
    <more-data >lorem ipsum</more-data>
  </item>
</item-syndication>
```

Here are the Request and Response Headers for the initial request:
[image: Request and Response Headers for initial request]

Here are the Request and Response Headers for the favicon, in case that's helpful:
[image: Request and Response Headers for favicon]

Comment: Could you please add the HTTP request and response headers? I think it might help understand exactly what communication is happening between the two services.

Comment: I added screenshots. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Would you also be able to grab the XHR for any POST request that occurs when the data from the XML Stream is loaded? I'll be better able to complete my answer with this information. (Firebug can do this for you and is my personal preference for Web Dev Tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the correct answer to this question is, I was using the wrong url. By using the correct URL, I was able to get the expected results in Nokogiri and curl.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the page is loading the XML using AJAX. (If you can grab the XHR using Firebug to see exactly the POST request they use to append the new XML it may give you/us a better idea)

It is a bit sad to say, but Nokogiri, as well as Mechanize (another XML parsing/scraping tool built on Nokogiri) do not support Javascript in any way, and therefore won't be able to get data that is pushed to the page via AJAX without reloading the page (which may or may not be an option for you).

But in a loop you have the option to load the page every 5 seconds for say 30 seconds, and compare the XML to the original scrape so that you do not get duplicates. How you would do so is completely up to you, but storing the values in a REXML and comparing to a newly scraped value does not seem like the worst option.

An alternative is to use a browser emulator that fully supports Javascript. Watir and Selenium are two that I know of which will allow you to prevent re-loading the page to accept the incoming changes (though I have personally not used either, as most of my work using Mechanize I've been able to work around Javascript by re-GETting the page or by sending a GET/POST by hand). The downside of using these two gems is the bulkiness that comes with emulating an entire browser.

Watir - http://rubygems.org/gems/watir

Selenium - http://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver